# silhouette score returns NaN

Tags: clustering, python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I'm computing silhouette_score from sklearn.metrics library in python, for hierarchical clustering. I'm computing this metric for few cuts of the tree (few options of number of clusters, K).
For some cuts of the tree, the silhouette_score returns nan result. Why?

here is my code:

```
silhouette_score(dist_matrix,tree,metric="precomputed")
```

where:

- `dist_matrix` is the distance matrix nXn (symmetric)
- `tree` - one option for cut of the tree (using `cut_tree(Z, n_clusters=K))`
- `metric` - precomputed as the distance matrix is already calculated based on some distance metric I calculated.

`NaN` result only happens for large amount of clusters (large K).here is the error I'm getting:

```
> /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py:205:
> RuntimeWarning:
> 
> invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as 
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
because it is about how to use Python without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have many duplicate distances.

If a(i)=b(i)=0 in Silhouette, you can get a division by 0.